# Drop shadow on masked window

Tags: c++, qt

In my project, I have a window that has been masked with `setMask(QRect())`. It works fine, but the shadow that the Window Manager leaves is gone. I definitely want that drop shadow effect on my program.

At first, I moved all of my objects into a single widget and had that widget cast a box shadow onto the MainWindow. Then I made the MainWindow transparent with `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true)` and `setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint)`. This did the job, however, having a frameless window caused many issue that I can't seem to fix. Namely, this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418494/qtframelesswindowhint-window-cant-be-recorded-with-obs

If I just do `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true)` or set the style sheet, the background becomes black, not transparent.

So my question is, how do I make the MainWindow transparent without removing the frame? Or how do I cast a shadow when using setMask?

Thanks for your time.